# How to display dynamic checkboxes using dojo

Tags: dojo

I want to display dynamic checkboxes by iterating json array object. Can anyone guide me how can we do this?

Comment: post just a little portion of your code !

Answer (score 0):

After doing some internet surfing and playing around code I able write below code, which working fine for my scenario. So thought it will be helpful for others.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < roleJSON.length; i++) {
                        var role = roleJSON[i]; 
                        var tr = dojo.create("tr",{id:"rolebasecheckbox"+i,'class':'rolebasecheckbox'});
                        alert("tr=" + tr);
                        var td= dojo.create("td",{innerHTML:'<input id="roleBaseCb_'+i+'" value="'+role.role_id+'" dojoType="dijit.form.CheckBox" onclick="alert('onclick event')" type="checkbox" /> <label for="roleBaseCb_'+i+'">'+role.role_name+'</label>',align:'center'},tr);
                        alert("td=" + td);
                        if(i==0){
                        alert("i is 0");
                        dojo.place(tr, "roleBaseComboTR", "after");
                        }else{
                            dojo.place(tr, "rolebasecheckbox"+(i-1), "after");  
                        }
                    }
```